# Slicing of a Pandas Series when index elements are not default (doesn't start with 0)

Tags: pandas

Created a Pandas Series in Python 3.7, providing the 'data' and 'index', where the data contains a list of list; len(list) = 6 and the index list contains the element which starts from 3 rather than starting from 0.
I want to slice the series.

```
import pandas as pd
li_a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],(9,10),(11,12)]
li_c = [3,4,5,6,7,8]
ser1 = pd.Series(data=li_a,index=li_c)
```

so, ser1[3] output: [1,2] i.e. the First element of the Series
I expected the output of ser1[3:] to be entire Series, but the output was

```
6      [7, 8]
7     (9, 10)
8    (11, 12)
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working that way because you are printing by row position, not using index:

`print(ser1[3:])`

output:

```
6 [7, 8]
7 (9, 10)
8 (11, 12)
```

If you want to print rows from specific index number you need to use `loc`

`print(ser1.loc[3:])`
output:

```
3      [1, 2]
4      [3, 4]
5      [5, 6]
6      [7, 8]
7     (9, 10)
8    (11, 12)
```

edited: from iloc to loc : 
`loc gets rows (or columns) with particular labels from the index.`

your full code (i have changed also your if **name** line:

```
def main():
    arr = np.arange(10,16)
    index1 = np.arange(3,9)
    ser1 = pd.Series(data=arr,index=index1)
    print(ser1)
    print(ser1.loc[3:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: so I've used the 'ser1.iloc[3:]' but it's still giving me the list from position 4.
moreover the doc of '.iloc' says 
'``.iloc[]`` is primarily integer position based (from ``0`` to
``length-1`` of the axis), but may also be used with a boolean
array.'

Comment: output was <br>
6      [7, 8] <br>
7     (9, 10) <br>
8    (11, 12) <br>
dtype: object

Comment: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def main():
    arr = np.arange(10,16)
    index1 = np.arange(3,9)
    ser1 = pd.Series(data=arr,index=index1)
    print(ser1)
    print(ser1.iloc[3:])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Comment: okay I found this method '.loc': this will actually calls by index rather than using '.iloc'.

Comment: yes, i wrote here iloc but in my interpreter i wrote loc , sory my bad